# 2 Columns in 1 Row using UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

Is it possible to get 2 columns in 1 row using UITableView instead of using UICollectionView.

The code I'm using returning 1 column per 1 row while I need 2 columns in 1 row at a time like the image attached.

[image: 2 Columns 1 Row]

The code used is swift 3:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return SCREEN_WIDTH / 4;
    }

    //Original Func
//  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
//      return 50;
//  }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return subCategoryMenuData.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        subCategoryTable.register(UINib(nibName: "subCategoryCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "subCategoryCellTableViewCell")

        //let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")

        let cell:subCategoryTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! subCategoryTableViewCell
        cell.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ic_placeholder.png")
        //NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getImageFromUrl(imageUrl:(subCategoryMenuData[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).thumbnail , imageView: cell.backgroundImageView)
        cell.categoryName.text = (subCategoryMenuData [indexPath.row] as? String)
        cell.categoryName?.textColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: REDCOLOR)

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        //cell.textLabel?.text = (subCategoryMenuData [indexPath.row] as? String)
        //let imageFilter = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:SCREEN_WIDTH - 60, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30))
        //cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        //cell.addSubview(imageFilter)

        return cell
    }
```

I tried changing the numberofSections and numberofRowsinSections, none of them have worked. Any solutions please?

Comment: No. Table views on iOS provide a single column of cells. That said, you can set up your cells to display two columns of information by using custom cells.

Comment: Please can you elaborate what you can custom cells. Thanks for the update changing to UICollectionView will force me to change multiple Storyboard Items + the XIB while the TableView will resolve the issue faster and easier.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get 2 columns in 1 row using UITableView instead of using UICollectionView

Basically, no. UICollectionView basically *is* nothing but a generalization of UITableView, allowing you to transcend its limitations. UITableView is one vertically scrolling column of single cells; that's all. If you want more than that, step up to UICollectionView.

Comment: Thanks for the update changing to UICollectionView will force me to change multiple Storyboard Items + the XIB while the TableView will resolve the issue faster and easier.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but it doesn't affect my answer. What you will be "forced to change" has nothing to do with the reality of what is possible, which is what you asked about.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer and cooperation. I'm setting up UICollection instead however since I've changed I got "Type 'subCategory' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'" error this is what I meant. Since Subcategory class is connected to a TableView in Storyboard and I'm trying to insert in it a CollectionView XIB here I see the conflict. I know the only reality I thought there might be a work around. Could please help me resolve this error, thanks again!

Comment: Please don't ask a different question in the comments. That is called "leeching" or "churning". If I've answered the question you _did_ ask, that's great. If you now have a new question, please ask it _as_ a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for any inconvenience caused, my bad. Thanks a lot, I'm trying to resolve my issues.